# Automatically adjust the height of a `stackedWidget` page to the height of the widgets placed on it

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I would like to adjust the height of the `stackedWidget` so that the height of the `QTextEdit` widget below it matches the height of the buttons on the active page of the `stackedWidget`. While the 4 `QPushButton` on page `extended` take up the entire space of the `stackedWidget`, the 2 `QPushButton` on page `normal` appear vertically in the middle and still have free space above and below.

But the 2 `QPushButton` on page `normal` should be at the top and the `QTextEdit` widget should be enlarged upwards. How can this be done?

---

### main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

### mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>601</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="locale">
   <locale language="English" country="UnitedKingdom"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="normal" native="true">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="normal_start_button">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Start</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="1">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="normal_stop_button">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Stop</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="extended">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="extended_quick_start_button">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Quick Start</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="1">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="extended_stop_button">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Stop</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="0">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="extended_slow_start_button">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Slow Start</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="1">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="extended_pause_button">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Pause</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QTextEdit" name="output"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

Screenshot of page `normal` with only 2 `QPushButton` and unused space above and below:

[image: Screenshot of page <code>normal</code>]

---

Screenshot of page `extended` with 4 `QPushButton` and optimal use of the available space:

[image: Screenshot of page <code>extended</code>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QStackedWidget takes as default height the default maximum height of the widget it contains, so in this case a possible solution is to set the height taking as reference the default height of the current widgets.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)
        self.stackedWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.adjustHeight)
        self.adjustHeight()

    def adjustHeight(self):
        h = self.stackedWidget.currentWidget().sizeHint().height()
        self.stackedWidget.setFixedHeight(h)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()

    def onTimeout():
        sw = main_window.stackedWidget
        sw.setCurrentIndex((sw.currentIndex() + 1) % sw.count())

    # test
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

    timer = QTimer(timeout=onTimeout)
    timer.start(1000)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```